# mysql: merge two columns into two rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following statement

```
SELECT disease.id, disease.name, disease_synonym.name FROM disease JOIN disease_synonym where diseaseId=code
```

the result is a table with an id and two columns with the names. how can i transform this into 2 columns with only an id and the name? (of course, the id will now occur several times)

Bye,

Nico

Comment: `SELECT disease.id, disease.name FROM` ? Which name do you want disease.name or disease_synonym.name?

Comment: Both. Eventually i want something like this:

Table(id,  name): Values:
(1  | disease.name)
(1  | disease_synonym.name) ... sorry if this is not very readble, comments dont allow linebreaks

Comment: A union query may be: in the first query you select column 1 and 2; in the second query you select column 1 and 3, combine their results using UNION.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways come to mind...

Run the query twice (once for name, and once for synonym), then union the results together...

```
SELECT disease.id, disease.name FROM disease

UNION ALL

SELECT disease.id, disease_synonym.name FROM disease JOIN disease_synonym where diseaseId=code
```

Or join on a two row table, and use a CASE statement to do a pivot...

```
SELECT
  disease.id,
  CASE WHEN pivot.field = 'name' THEN disease.name
       WHEN pivot.field = 'syno' THEN disease_synonym.name
  END
FROM
  disease
INNER JOIN
  disease_synonym
    ON diseaseId=code
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 'name' AS field UNION ALL SELECT 'syno' AS field) AS Pivot
```

Comment: The first one works. already tried something in this direction but this ones better. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `SELECT disease.id, disease_synonym.name FROM ...` don't you? Just displaying the synonym names?